# Prove that if $n$ is divisible by a prime number $p$ then neither $n^2 +1$ nor $n^2 -1$ will be divisible by $p$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

I know this holds for $p=3$, but can it be generalized for any prime number? Can it be generalized further for any integer $p \in \Bbb N $ ?

Comment: "then neither $n^2+1$ nor $n^2−1$ will be divisible" What won't they be divisible by?

Comment: Are you sure you are asking the question you mean to ask? @Dhruv 's answer below doesn't even need $p$ to be prime.

Comment: @EthanBolker Right. Any $p>1$ would do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If integer $p$ divides both  $n$  and $(n^2-1)(n^2+1)$

$p$ must divide $$n\cdot n^3-(n^2-1)(n^2+1)=?$$

Comment: Please correct your proof :)

Comment: You only proved that $p$ cannot divide **both** $n^2-1$ and $n^2+1$.

Comment: @KennyLau The proof is correct. It isn't both, if $a|b \implies a|bc$.

Comment: @KennyLau, I've proved : $p$  can not divide $n$  and $(n^2-1)(n^2+1)$  simultaneously

Comment: **not both** does not mean **neither** :)

Comment: @KennyLau Bhattacharjee is right; if $p$ doesn't divide $ab$ then how could it possibly divide $a$ or $b$?

Comment: This proof is correct, but very roundabout and confusing (see all the comments). @Dhruv 's is much more direct and understandable, and doesn't even require $p$ to be prime!

Comment: sorry my fault :)

Answer (score 5):

If $p$ divides $n$ wouldn't $p$ divide $n^2$ as well. If $p$ a prime number divides $n^2$ will it divide $n^2+1$ or $n^2-1$? The lowest prime number is $2$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:-

We have $n$ is divisible by $p$.

So,$n^2$ must be divisible by $p$.(why?)

So,clearly $n^2+1$ will leave remainder $1$.(why?)

Now,try to find out what remainder $n^2-1$ will leave.